# Codeigniter active Record

Tags: codeigniter

Iam unable to understand following:

$this->db->select('1', FALSE);

Can some one elaborate it in simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter is the field names or values in your case `1` from your table, the second parameter FALSE prevents the first parameter being wrapped in backticks.  You'd use this is you were nesting a sub query as the first parameter.

For further information see the [Codigniter docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select) which are incredibly useful.